# How so I execute $query->orderBy('FIELD(node.nid, 5,12,3,6)', 'ASC')?

Tags: database, 8

I am currently converting code from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. So far I am unable to find resources on how to convert the call to `orderBy()` which uses an expression.

```
$query->orderBy("FIELD(node.nid, '5,12,3,6')", 'ASC');
```

Based on [D8 Select::orderBy](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Query!Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AorderBy/8.2.x), it only accepts alias or fields.

What is the code I should use in Drupal 8?

Comment: $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(thread, 1, (LENGTH(thread) - 1))', 'order_field');
    $query->orderBy('order_field', 'ASC'); Try this

Comment: I tried that but it will not work as it adds the FIELD command to the select fields.

e.g. SELECT FIELD(node.nid, 5,12,3,6') AS order_field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a workaround by implementing a CASE statement then sorting by the value.

```
$query->addExpression("
    CASE node.nid
        WHEN 5 THEN 1
        WHEN 12 THEN 2
        WHEN 3 THEN 3
        WHEN 6 THEN 4
        ELSE 5
    END
", 'order_field');

$query->orderBy("order_field", 'ASC');
```

Hopefully they'll add another function to handle these special statements in the future.