# Prioritise condition in QueryInterface

Tags: database, 10

I have an overview with a search field. The query should search on both the title and description, but I would want to show my results that have the search parameter in the title first in the list.
I am using a QueryInterface and have following condition group

```
 $group = $query->orConditionGroup();
 $group->condition('title', "%" . $searchString . "%", 'LIKE');
 $group->condition('field_description', "%" . $searchString . "%", 'LIKE');
 $query->condition($group);
```

Does anyone know a way to use a groupBy in a QueryInterface to do something like this

```
ORDER BY
(title LIKE "%" . $searchString . "%") DESC,
(field_description LIKE "%" . $searchString . "%") DESC;
```

Comment: Not sure it's the most efficient, but this is one outline way to do it: use `$query->addTag('foo');`, then implement [`hook_query_foo_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.8.x) to get access to the regular query once it's been built. From there you can add `CASE` expressions for your fields (example [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199806/how-so-i-execute-query-orderbyfieldnode-nid-5-12-3-6-asc)), then use `$query->orderBy` with those added expressions

Comment: As a slight aside, it'd be a good idea to inject the `database` service and use its `escapeLike` method on `$searchString`. Without it, if someone searches for a string with a `%` character you're risking an SQL error or at least inaccurate results

Comment: `condition()` is for `WHERE` clauses, which have a different effect than `ORDER BY`. `ORDER BY` would then not show first the rows for which the desired value is found in the title and then the rows for which the same value is found in a field description.

Comment: @Clive Can i use my variable $searchstring in this hook?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to pass it through, but anything you can declare in your current context you can also declare in the hook (or define a service to give you that data if you use it in more than one place)